# Returning always the last image into Label

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-except

I'm making a web scraping on a website for a private game server using Python. In a part of this website prints the result of the last nation war winner and show 2 messages: `"Capella Ganhou!!"` and `"Procyon Ganhou!!"` using the `BeautfulSoup` library. I made a condition for each event for show the winner nation image into the Label by an url. But for some reason it shows always the last image url and I don't  know what is happening. Here is the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.display import Image, display
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO

def capella_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    try:
        resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[5].string)
        label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg, font=("Consolas", 25)).pack()
    except:
        return False

def procyon_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    try:
        resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[4].string[3:])
        label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg, font=("Consolas", 25)).pack()
    except:
        return False

root = Tk()
root.title("Resultado TG Cabal Ghost")

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.cabaleasy.com") as url: page = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

if capella_tg():
    url = "https://i.imgur.com/AHLqtt0.jpg"    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u: raw_data = u.read()        
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label = Label(image=image).pack()
else:
    procyon_tg()
    url = "https://i.imgur.com/TQyCnfD.jpg"    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u: raw_data = u.read()        
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label = Label(image=image).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `capella_tg()` returns either `None` or `False`, so the line `if capella_tg()` will always be `False`.

Comment: If I use the `if` structure he will accuse that there is no such argument at the present time. I'm trying to descover the better solution but it's so hard to me as a beginner Python programmer.